# solving system of n equations with n unknowns with python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

is it possible to solve a system of n equations with n unknowns (3 for exemple) so that the sum of all elements of the system tends to a value k

```
O<k <n
```

matrix(nx1) (vector)

```
a.x1+b.y1+c.z1-U_1
a.x2+b.y2+c.z2-U_2
...
a.xn+b.yn+c.zn-U_n
```

Comment: I don't see any equation.

Answer (score 1):

i need an algorithm to solve this system then i will use python

```
sum(axi+byi+czi+...-gi)=k
```

a,b,c unknowns